# Android Studio build tools 26.0.2 error in Ubuntu

Tags: android-sdk-tools, android-studio-3.0, android-build

I'm using Ubuntu and for installing Android Studio, I downloaded it directly from google (both SDK and Studio), I've got Android Build Tools 27, but when I want to make the project the app shows me an error that says you don't have build tools 26.0.2!
I also changed the module settings of the project but it does not work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem.When I download and install this build tools version from sdk manager, this error is never showing again.